# UFT hangs after "Press" method

Tags: .net, qtp, swfobject, hp-uft

I have an issue with my script.
Here is my script:

```
SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").SwfObject("swfname path:=;MDIMain").SwfWindow("swfname:=ActiveReportPreview").SwfObject("swfname:=Viewer1").SwfToolbar("micclass:=SwfToolbar").Press 2
SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").Dialog("text:=Print").SwfButton("text:=&Print").Click
```

This code suppose to:

1. Click on "print" icon -> "Print" dialog opens
2. Click on "Print" button on the "Print" Dialog.

But after first line, UFT hangs and doesn't proceed to the next line.

What could be the solution?

**P.S.** when I close the "Print" dialog manually, UFT works fine again.
I'm using UFT version 11.5.

Comment: It maybe that QTP is not able to find the object described in second line.

So when you say that after closing the dialog manually UFT works fine, means it gives error saying that object not found?? if so, it maybe possible that QTP is able to find parent object but trying to find inner objects for eg. it is able to find SwfWindow but not Dialog

Also I am not sure if you can use both SwfWindow and Dialog in same object description because one is .net form object and other is of Standard Windows form object

Things to try, Open the print dialog and check each hierarchy of the objects

Comment: Things to Try, Open the print dialog and check each hierarchy of the objects manually

eg : first check SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").highlight, if this works then try SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").Dialog("text:=Print").highlight and so on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Highlight method worked perfectly for me!

Comment: Good to see it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try highlighting the object first, and see if UFT can actually see this object. 
This is how I'd write the code:

```
Set myobj = SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").SwfObject("swfname path:=;MDIMain").SwfWindow("swfname:=ActiveReportPreview").SwfObject("swfname:=Viewer1").SwfToolbar("micclass:=SwfToolbar")
myobj.Press 2  '//not entirely sure if this line will work, but modify if needed
wait 2 '//give it the time to sync
If SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").Dialog("text:=Print").Exist() Then
   SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").Dialog("text:=Print").highlight()
   SwfWindow("swfname:=MDIMain").Dialog("text:=Print").SwfButton("text:=&Print").Click  
End If
```

Comment: Thank you!! It did work for me!!. Though i've used work around (ctrl+P) for printing, but your solution is perfect for other buttons in the swftoolbar!